# Package sidecap not working with Lyx 2.0.4

Tags: lyx, sidecap

I tryed to use the package `sidecap` to put the caption beside the immage,
I didnt found any other (working ^^) way to do that apart `sidecap`,
but it is not working.

I tried to make a new file, article, add

```
\usepackage{sidecap}
```

in the preamble, and did the following:

- add a float figure,
- insert an image inside the box "float figure"
- write down a caption on the box labelled as "figure 1".

When I compile, the caption and the string "figure 1:" is just under the image.

Idk where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

### Sidecap module

There is a module that uses the `sidecap` package available from http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/jrioux/lyx/ (via http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules). Download the `sidecap.module` file and follow the instructions on the that site for installing.

In LyX, go to Document --> Settings --> Modules, and add the Sidecap module which now should be available. To add a figure with a side caption, simply choose *Insert --> Float --> Figure (side caption)*. Similarly for tables.

### Original answer -- without modules

I'm afraid `sidecap` doesn't change the behaviour of normal figures, it only defines new environments where the caption will be placed on the side. To use `sidecap` I think you will have to add these environments "manually", in ERTs.

After adding `\usepackage{sidecap}`, you can do the following where you want to add a figure:

1. Add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and type `\begin{SCfigure}`.
2. Move the cursor outside the ERT, and add the image as you normally would, e.g. via the button on the toolbar.
3. Add a second ERT after the image, and type

   ```
   \caption{<Your caption here>}
   \end{SCfigure}
   ```

An example of how it may look inside LyX:

[image]

#### Cross referencing

If you want to add a cross reference to such a figure you have two options I think:

1. In the second ERT, write `\label{yourlabel}` *after* the `\caption{}`. The problem with this option, is that the label doesn't show up in the LyX's GUI, so you'll have to write in in manually.
2. Write `\end{SCfigure}` in a separate ERT, and in between this one and the one with `\caption{}`, add a label with the button on the toolbar or Insert --> Label.
   [image]

For both cases, instead of writing the caption in an ERT, you could also add it using Insert --> Caption.

Comment: So the module sidecap does not work? I am having trouble using it with Lyx 2.0.5.1

Comment: @venik I tried that module after seeing your question, and it worked fine. If you're unable to make it work you could ask a new question, but please explain what you've tried and how it fails.

Comment: the link is broken