# How do you move a figure caption in lyx?

Tags: floats, lyx, lyx-layouts

When inserting a figure in Lyx (i.e. Insert->Float->Figure), the figure caption is automatically inserted below the image.

The image that I am inserting is long but narrow and therefore the automatic placement of the caption wastes lots of space.

Is there a way to have the graphics on the left hand side of the figure float and the caption on the right hand side?

Comment: See if [Package sidecap not working with Lyx 2.0.4](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/83014#83014) helps. Another option would be to use two minipages, similar to [How can you place a figure caption inside a table using LyX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102111/102114#102114)

Comment: The sidecap module works great!